# Get userid from auth0 session localStorage

Tags: vue.js, auth0

I'm in the process of implementing auth0 login in my project, and to be as fast as possible I'm using a hosted login page. Following the auth0 vue docs I've got up and running quickly and I can login and logout users.

Now, I'm trying to create a user profile page with a route of `user/:id`. For the `:id` part I want to use the user_id of the user profile, but I'm having issues understanding the optimal way to get it. I realize I can use the auth0 api users endpoint but I'm not sure that's the correct way. Do I actually need to make an API call to the users endpoint each time an user clicks their profile? Is there no better way to get the user_id, maybe from the `id_token` which is set in localStorage upon login?

Even better, is there a way to get actual user ids? I know that if I would setup my own login with my own db, I'd have an auto incrementing id which I'd use for user id. This does not seem possible with Auth0, or am I wrong about that?

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work for Auth0.

The `idToken` returned at the end of the authentication / authorization is a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io). This token contains the Auth0 `user_id`  as the `sub` (subject) claim (property).

If you are using Auth0.js or our AuthService tutorial, Auth0.js will decode this token and give it to you as `idTokenPayload` object in the `authResult`. This can be used to identify the user as `idTokenPayload.sub`.

You can store this object as a whole in localStorage or simply decode the token that you accquired from localStorage. However, please note that you should *validate* the token after accquiring it from localStorage aswell.

To avoid all the above, you can simply use the `checkSession` method each time your application bootstraps to get a new copy of the `accessToken` / `idToken` and rely on that directly :)